# how to fix the alteration of visibility inside a recyclerview's viewholder layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a recyclerview using the following xml as a list item for each of its views

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardElevation="2dp">
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/item_question_name"
            style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/app_margin"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/item_question_question"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/item_question_needs_sync"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="This is the name" />
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView android:id="@+id/item_question_needs_sync"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/item_question_name"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/item_question_name"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_sync" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/item_question_question"
            style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/app_margin"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/item_question_type"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/item_question_name"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/item_question_name"
            tools:text="this is the question" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/item_question_type"
            style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/app_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/app_margin"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/item_question_separator"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/item_question_info"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/item_question_question"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/item_question_question"
            tools:text="Four faces which are awesome" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/item_question_info"
            style="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/item_question_type"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/item_question_type"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/item_question_type"
            tools:text="answered ALL the questions" />
        <View android:id="@+id/item_question_separator"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/item_question_buttons"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/item_question_info" />
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout android:id="@+id/item_question_buttons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/item_question_separator">
            <Button android:id="@+id/item_question_delete"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/item_question_button_delete"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/item_question_edit"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/item_question_edit"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/item_question_button_edit"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/item_question_delete"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/item_question_view"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/item_question_delete"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/item_question_delete" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/item_question_view"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/item_question_button_view"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/item_question_delete"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/item_question_start"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/item_question_edit"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/item_question_delete" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/item_question_start"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/item_question_button_start"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/item_question_delete"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/item_question_view"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/item_question_delete" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

my problem is that when the user clicks on the view I have the viewholder toggling whether the @+id/item_question_buttons will be shown or not like so:

```
void bind_view(Info info, boolean selected) {
   //load the data from info
    .....
   // _buttons is a View object where I stored the constraint layout with the buttons

   if (selected) {
       _buttons.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
   } else {
       _buttons.setVisibility(GONE);
   }
}
```

my problem is that every other time (i.e. the 2nd 4th 6th etc) the user toggles the visibility of the _buttons View the view expands to triple the normal size (which is the same as the max height a button can have).

I solved it by using android:maxLines="1" but I was wandering , why does this happen? and is there a better way to fix this?

thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Comment: Why are you using a nested constraint layout ?  If you did that just to toggle visibility of all buttons in one line, you can do it using the Group feature from the last beta release.

Comment: Which view get it fixed when you change the maxLine attribute ?

Comment: unfortunatelly I'm working on xamarin, and we don't get the latest features as the rest of the world, it took them 9 months to translate constraint layout, and yes I am doing it for the visibility thing, I'll check the group feature you mentioned though, just in case it is translated

Comment: I put it in every button and it seemed to fix it, what also seemed to help was removing the vertical chain and just adding one view under the other, basically I removed most BottomToTopOf attributes

Comment: @Cruces you could also put the buttons under a single `LinearLayout`

Comment: yeah that's what I used to do up to now, but since google seems to be headed to the constraint layout way, I figured I should change everything, plus this is how they do it in ios design, and since someday I'm hoping to also be involved in ios development I thought I should start getting used to it